# FB comments mixed with non-FB comments?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

Can I show non-FB comments in between FB comments?

If I understand correctly comments are shown via iFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about [Facebook comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), then the answer is NO.
You can't place non-fb comments 'in between' fb comments.

Comment: by the way, do you want to use facebook comments besides wordpress comments?

Comment: yes that is correct or potentially another commenting system similar to that of WP

Comment: If you are using wordpress, you can check these two wordpress plugin:
[Comment Disable Master](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-disable-master/) & [Total Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/total-facebook/) . they'll allow you to use both comment system or just one of them. They've lots of amazing options too. Hope this helps